# На чем основаны нейролингвистические методы обучения языкам и насколько они эффективны?

Tags: методика

Можно ли научиться грамотно писать и говорить за четыре занятия, как предлагается в рекламе, используя подобные методики?

Четыре удивительных сеанса с Волшебницей – и ошибок нет!!!**

Что вы об этом думаете? Зачем учить 11 лет  орфографию и грамматику, если есть чудо-методика? Нейролингвист, 4 диплома, патент на изобретение, сертификат качества РФ. Прикоснется волшебной палочкой к вашей голове ― и ошибок нет. Безупречная грамотность, правильно построенная речь.

**А вдруг это правда или хотя бы что-то правдивое в этом есть?** Гипноз, например? С другой стороны, как это скажется на вашем здоровье в целом?

Comment: Мало верится, но - а вдруг?

Comment: Четыре сеанс, глядишь и к.ф.н и д.ф.н станешь!

Comment: Может быть, научат, как подключиться к общему информационному полю? Есть же случаи, когда люди вдруг после каких-то потрясений начинали говорить на иностранном языке, как на родном.

Comment: Если хотите подойти серьезно, то изучите патент (есть там что-то о чуде?). Далее. Обещают ускорение в 15-20 раз. Допустим. Определите затраты времени (например 11 лет), разделите на 20 - сколько получится? А обещают все за 4 -12 сеансов, вот и решайте, насколько это реально.

Comment: @М_Г, попытка не пытка. Можно попробовать. Я живу в Армении, иначе я пошел бы туда ради интереса.

Comment: Arina, пожалуйста, обратите внимание на раздел "Опросы" правил сайта.